# Manipulate input string while doing a regex search

Tags: javascript, regex

trying to find every match in a string and process it with a custom function and replace it in the string. When I set text = to the new string though, it never changes, and in the end remains the unchanged.

```
function submit () {
    var searchTerm = document.querySelector('#search-term').value;
    var replaceFunction = Function('input', document.querySelector('#function').value);
    var text = '<part id="cursor_crosshair" x="96" y="32" w="16" h="16" focusx="7" focusy="7" />';
    var output = text;
    var regex = new RegExp('\d', 'g');
    var match, matches = [];

    //search for replacements
    while ((match = regex.exec(text)) != null) {


        var beforeMatch = output.substring(0, match.index);
        var afterMatch = output.substring(match.index + match[0].length, text.length);

        text = beforeMatch + replaceFunction(match[0]) + afterMatch;
         console.log(text);

    }
    console.log('result', text);
}

function replaceFunction (input) {
    return input * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve same result with far less code using `replace()` and its [function's callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) that takes `match` as parameter.

```js
var text = '<part id="cursor_crosshair" x="96" y="32" w="16" h="16" focusx="7" focusy="7" />';

text = text.replace(/\d+/g, function(match){
  return parseInt(match) * 2;
})

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use `\\` for escape sequence if you are using `RegExp` constructor. Alternatively you can use the RegExp literal as shown below.  Moreover you are using only `\d` which is going to match a single digit. Instead you should be using `\d+` that will match the complete number.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary. For example, the following are equivalent:
>
> var re = /\w+/;
>
> var re = new RegExp('\\w+');

Then you are trying to manipulate the string using a loop. Instead simply use `replace` function as shown below.

```js
function submit () {
    // var searchTerm = document.querySelector('#search-term').value;
    // var replaceFunction = Function('input', document.querySelector('#function').value);
    var text = '<part id="cursor_crosshair" x="96" y="32" w="16" h="16" focusx="7" focusy="7" />';
    var output = text;
    var regex = new RegExp('\\d+', 'g'); // <<<<<< RegExp constructor
    // OR 
    regex = /\d+/g; // <<<<<<< RegExp literal
    var match, matches = [];

    console.log(text);
    output = text.replace(regex, replaceFunction);
    console.log('result', output);
}

function replaceFunction (input) {
    return parseInt(input) * 2;
}

submit();
```

Disclaimer: Using RegExp for manipulating HTML elements and attributes is not a good idea and you may end up in unexpected issues if its not used carefully. Use it at your own risk.